# Возможно ли добавить столбец перед столбцом

Tags: c#, mysql

У меня есть команда которая просто добавляет столбец, возможно ли добавить этот столбец например перед столбцом "Финиш".

---

Возможно можно как то считать все столбцы которые есть в базе данных перенести их в переменную, затем удалить программно в переменной в которую все названия столбцов попадут. Допустим есть у меня Старт Предмет1 Пердмет2 Предмет3 Финиш. я беру заношу названия этих столбцов в переменную. Затем удаляю там Финиш. Каким то образом извлекаю последнее название и в итоге мы применяем AFTER.

---

Или как предложили в коментах - Ничего не надо удалять. Надо просто запросить имя поля, у которого в нужной таблице нужной схемы значение ORDINAL_POSITION на единицу меньше, чем у поля с именем Финиш в той же таблице той же схемы.

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Students ADD COLUMN Старт TEXT", sqlConnection);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17695539/5752652 https://stackoverflow.com/q/2934312/5752652

Comment: там AFTER - это после

Comment: А зачем? Ну действительно? Просто при чтении выводите их в нужном вам порядке: `select x, y from table` или `select y, x from table`

Comment: Там сложная система) очень надо так. Там просто каждый раз будут создаваться колонки и нужно их создавать перед колонкой Финиш. Что бы не создавать каждый раз колонку Финиш. Как то так

Comment: "You only have AFTER or FIRST. No before." Поэтому я дал вторую ссылку на reorder.

Comment: Если пойти сложным путем, то можно получить все столбцы которые есть и  удалить там Финиш. Но эт тяжко для меня пока что

Comment: Та нет ты не понял сути, удалить программно в переменной в которую все названия столбцов попадут. Допустим есть у меня Старт Предмет1 Пердмет2 Предмет3 Финиш. я беру заношу названия этих столбцов в переменную. Затем удаляю там Финиш. Каким то образом извлекаю последнее название

Comment: Располагать поля в структуре в каком-то порядке - не имеет никакого смысла. Всё равно при ПРАВИЛЬНЫХ запросах в них указываются конкретные поля в требуемом порядке (`SELECT *` - это исключительно для лентяев, по большому счёту звезда в запросах имеет смысл только в одном месте - в аргументе групповой функции `COUNT()`).

Comment: @Akina в моем случае мне нужно так как я написал

Comment: *Возможно можно как то считать все столбцы которые есть в базе данных перенести их в переменную, затем удалить программно в переменной в которую все названия столбцов попадут.* Легко. [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html), ORDINAL_POSITION.

Comment: @Akina А вот тут немного по подробнее ) Нам нужна там удалить в перемнной Финиш и считать последний столбец

Comment: Ничего не надо удалять. Надо просто запросить имя поля, у которого в нужной таблице нужной схемы значение `ORDINAL_POSITION` на единицу меньше, чем у поля с именем `Финиш` в той же таблице той же схемы.

Comment: Окей как это сделать ? Я просто хз особо не разбираюсь

Comment: Если не сложно можно код пожалуйста